# Iterate through many tables to get data (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

First of all I'm kinda new to MySql, so the solution to this may be very easy and I'm not seeing it.

This is the problem: I have to get all the prices related to a kind of event and I'm having troubles doing so.

Basically, I have to get from the table where I get the event type, to the one where I get its price.
That's the path to follow to get from the initial table to the one with the result:

I start like this, giving the event type

```
std_event.type = <my type of event goes here>
```

from here I have to iterate from a table to another comparing the IDs, doing something like this:

```
std_event.id = std_concert.event_id
AND
std_concert.id = std_slot.concert_id
AND
std_slot.id = std_slot_deal.slot_id
AND
std_slot_deal.accepted = 1;
```

At this point in the `SELECT` at the beginning I would have had

```
std_slot_deal.cachet
```

so I would have got the cachet (which is the price I was talking about) at the end of all this.

Thanks for your help!

p.s. In case you need it, this is my query at the moment:

```
SELECT std_event.type, std_slot_deal.cachet
FROM std_event
INNER JOIN std_concert, std_slot, std_slot_deal
ON std_event.type = '.$evt_type.'
AND
std_event.id = std_concert.event_id
AND
std_concert.id = std_slot.concert_id
AND
std_slot.id = std_slot_deal.slot_id
AND
std_slot_deal.accepted = 1;
```

(yes, I'm sending the quest through PHP, this `'.$evt_type.'` is the input event type)

**EDIT**
Here's the tables' structures I was asked for:

*std_event*: `id(I use it to link to event_id in std_concert table), title, description, type(the input data I use), image, ...`

*std_concert*: `id(I use it to link to concert_id in std_slot table), date, place, street, city, ..., event_id`

*std_slot*: `id(I use it to link to slot_id in std_slot_deal table), concert_id, due_date, ...`

*std_slot_deal*: `id, club_id, artist_id, slot_id, ..., accepted, cachet(the result I need)`

With this query I want to retrive all the cachet of the events with the given type basically.
I know the database is quite messy but I have to work on that, I don't even have a documentation or anything.

Comment: Please post your table structure with relationship of each other.

Comment: Ok, I'm editing the question right now.

Comment: Done, let me know if you need anything else and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, this may help you

```
SELECT std_event.type, std_slot_deal.cachet
FROM std_event
INNER JOIN std_concert ON std_event.id = std_concert.event_id
INNER JOIN std_slot ON std_slot.concert_id = std_concert.id
INNER JOIN std_slot_deal ON std_slot.id = std_slot_deal.slot_id
WHERE std_event.type = '.$evt_type.'
AND
std_slot_deal.accepted = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works just fine! I guess I'll have to take a look again at INNER JOIN function to better understand how it works...